# Where do Gremlins come from?

Tags: gremlins

I know the first Mogwai, Gizmo was bought in a pet shop. Other Gremlins were created out of him after water was spilt onto him.

My question is, is there any information on the *origin* of the Mogwai/Gremlins?

[image]

Comment: Gizmo is a Mogwai, not a Gremlin...

Comment: According to the novelization by George Gipes, the Mogwai were genetically engineered by an alien called Mogturmen. The gremlin-izing effect was a genetic flaw. There's more info at the gremlin wiki: http://gremlins.wikia.com/wiki/Mogturmen

Comment: The answer is asia, the drunkard who was a pilot and fought against either vietnam or korea recognozed them as gremlins, the old man who advised the father againt taking and refused to sell is from the orient and claims it is from his home

Comment: Isn’t it strongly implied that the movie might be in the same universe as that cartoon where gremlins attack the plane? Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Before I read this answer, I assumed that they were like, a mystical species that lived in the east and only a few knew about them, because humans weren’t meant to meddle with them. Those select few would include the guy in Chinatown.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Within the film universe, no origin is offered for the genesis of the Mogwai or their malevolent counterparts, the Gremlins.

In the novelisation "[Gremlins: The Movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlins#Novelization)", we are advised that the Mogwai are the result of alien genetic engineering gone awry. They're a species engineered long ago on the planet Enz by a being named Morgturmen.

> "*... the galactic powers ordered the Mogwai sent to every inhabitable
>   planet in the universe, their purpose being to inspire alien beings
>   with their peaceful spirit and intelligence and to instruct them in
>   the ways of living without violence and possible extinction. Among the
>   planets selected for early Mogwai population were Kelm-6 in the
>   Poraisti Range, Clinpf-A of the Beehive Pollux, and the third
>   satellite of MinorSun#67672, a small but fertile body called Earth by
>   its inhabitants.*"

[image: Mogwai Dance]

Comment: that gif...I am not certain it invokes a peaceful spirit in me.

Comment: @flq - I chose it because the one above is a bit gruesome...

Comment: Wow. So Mogwai were created by aliens?!? That’s a whole lot to bring in to it, but it works. Kind of poses more questions than it answers.

Comment: @Samalot - The novelisation is hella weird with lots (and lots) of added nonsense